# How can I get iOS time synchronized behind a firewall?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova, time, ntp

I have iPod Touches behind our corporate network, these devices do not have Internet access. I really need these devices to have up to date time...

I'd like to set iOS to use an internal NTP server but AFAIK iOS will not allow me to do so. If so, I'm all ears on how to do this. I've considered other options on how to get sync'd time on these devices:

1. Spoof Apple's time server DNS hostname on our internal network to an internal NTP server. Honestly I'm not sure how difficult this would be and I'm guessing it would be impossible to get my network admins to do it.
2. I am wondering if my application can set the time on the device. I could make a webservice call for the current time (to an internal server) and just set it within the app. Is this possible? I need to dig into iOS API's and am not that familiar with the platform. I do have an inherited hybrid Obj-C/Phonegap application I can test in.

Any other advice for my time problem?

Comment: You can't set time programmatically . I am curious.. what does [NSDate date] call return on these devices?

Comment: Bummer. I have not tried using NSDate. Our Date code is running in JavaScript inside PhoneGap. We've had dates come back as far back as the Unix epoch. My best guess is the device's battery drains and then loses its time. Since their is no Internet connection it never gets set until the user manually corrects it. It's near impossible for me to reproduce unfortunately. Just looking at logs on the server.

Answer (score -1):

One option is to get GPS time. Try this.

```
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

CLLocation* gps = [[CLLocation alloc]
                   initWithLatitude:(CLLocationDegrees) 0.0
                   longitude:(CLLocationDegrees) 0.0];
NSDate* now = gps.timestamp;
```

Comment: Would this be of any use on an iPod Touch? If I'm not mistaken an iPod Touch does not include a GPS. Plus I do not expect we'd get GPS reception indoors or is there something going on here that I am not grokking? Thanks.

Comment: ooooh... yes.. you are right.. only other suggestion i have is to create an api on your server to return the time.. it will obviously be offset by the network lag. sorry

Comment: `CLLocation.timestamp` is not GPS time, it sadly is just the system time.